# Send email multiple time without repeating the email code

Tags: php, email

I have 6 basic arrays, divided in 2 groups, each group in 3, so each array contain name, dob, id, email, the main idea is to send and email per group depending on the birthday, if the users birthday is in 2 weeks send email 1, if is in 2 days send email 2... the following is what I use to send the file and to build a final array for the report...

```
    foreach ($mno as $ko=>$vo) {
        $m_cump = date('m-d', strtotime($vo['dob']));
        // The birthday is TODAY!
        if($today == $m_cump) { $td_dob[]= array('nombre'=>$vo['name'],'resp_id'=>$vo['resp_id'],'email'=>$vo['email'],'dob'=>$vo['dob']);  
        // Here is the bulky code for the email, is huge since I use HTML for the emails
}
        // The birthday is in 2 days
        if($tds == $m_cump) {$dob_in_2_days[]= array('nombre'=>$vo['name'],'resp_id'=>$vo['resp_id'],'email'=>$vo['email'],'dob'=>$vo['dob']);
      // Here is the bulky code for the email, is huge since I use HTML for the emails
    }
        // The birthday is in 2 weeks
        if($tws == $m_cump) {$dob_in_2_weeks[]= array('nombre'=>$vo['name'],'resp_id'=>$vo['resp_id'],'email'=>$vo['email'],'dob'=>$vo['dob']); 
        // Here is the bulky code for the email, is huge since I use HTML for the emails
        }
    }
```

So as you can see I have to repeat the code for the email for each IF in the FOREACH() ... I don't know if I can just call a function and send the correct email.. `sendEmail1($vo->email);` or something similar that way I can build the email and then I can just reuse it without the need to repeat the whole code... I'm not good at building functions that is why I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an email function in that file or an included file, and pass the necessary variables to it.

Basic example:

```
function SendEmail($name, $email, $when){
$headers = ""; // your email headers
if ( $when == "TODAY!" ) {
$subject = "$name, happy birthday!!!";
$message = "Hey $name, \n\n We just wanted to say HAPPY BIRTHDAY!!!";
} else {
$subject = "$name, your birthday is in $when!";
$message = "$name, we just wanted to remind you, your birthday is in $when! Can't wait :)";
}
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Then whenever you need to send an email simply do something like:

```
SendEmail("$vo['name']", "$vo['email']", "TODAY!!");
```

Comment: Awesome!, it works fine, I did some modifications to fit my needs, one of them was the `IF $when`, since the send email get executed inside the `foreach()`, and by that I already know the "WHEN" so that is not needed in my case, the header need to output the "HTML" and the message is "unique" per user... like I said I change it to fit my need, in other words thank you, is working perfectly!...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `else` on your code? So when the condition appears, it will be out from the loop. Plus, if you don't need the `$ko` variable inside the loop, I prefer to not use it.

```
<?php 

foreach ($mno as $vo)
{
    $m_cump = date('m-d', strtotime($vo['dob']));
    // The birthday is TODAY!
    if ($today == $m_cump)
    {
        $td_dob[] = array('nombre' => $vo['name'], 'resp_id' => $vo['resp_id'], 'email' => $vo['email'], 'dob' => $vo['dob']);
    }
    // The birthday is in 2 days
    elseif ($tds == $m_cump)
    {
        $dob_in_2_days[] = array('nombre' => $vo['name'], 'resp_id' => $vo['resp_id'], 'email' => $vo['email'], 'dob' => $vo['dob']);   
    }
    // The birthday is in 2 weeks
    elseif ($tws == $m_cump)
    {
        $dob_in_2_weeks[] = array('nombre' => $vo['name'], 'resp_id' => $vo['resp_id'], 'email' => $vo['email'], 'dob' => $vo['dob']);
    }
}

function sending_email($data = array(), $type = '')
{
    switch ($type)
    {
        case 'today':
            //...
            break;
        case 'in_2_days' :
            //...
            break;
        case 'in_2_weeks':
            //...
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: That wont work, the reason that it wont work is because, first the `elseif` is use when you know you might get false on the first option, but in this case always is gonna be true, since I'm working with a DB which contain about 150K records and because my arrays are build to only get birthdays from, today, in 2 days, and 2 weeks... but thanks.